# Click module ignoring subgroup commands

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

Trying to implement the example from the palletsprojects website:
https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/commands/

```
imoport click

@click.group()
@click.option('--debug/--no-debug', default=False)
def cli(debug):
    click.echo('Debug mode is %s' % ('on' if debug else 'off'))

@cli.command()  # @cli, not @click!
def sync():
    click.echo('Syncing')
```

The following lines produce no output in my terminal:

```
python cli_test.py cli
python cli_test.py sync
python cli_test.py
```

When I'd expect 'Syncing' to be printed for the second line.

Comment: From the documentation you can read that `@click.group()` produces a `Command` object, which you still need to [invoke](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/quickstart/#basic-concepts-creating-a-command).

Comment: it's invoked for the function sync

Comment: Well then you should probably invoke `cli`. :)

Comment: I want the command sync to run, I do not get why python cli_test.py sync works

Comment: But clearly `sync` is a sub-command of the `cli` group, so `python cli_test.py sync` will only call `sync` when the `cli` command is invoked as the main command.

Comment: I do not know if I get you right but python cli_test.py cli sync does noething as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're (presumably from how I understand the library) supposed to invoke a master command after setting up the commands and groups. Append this to your code:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

And `python cli_test.py sync` should in turn call the `sync` command.